# Image flicker in a JFrame

Tags: java, buffer, jframe, flicker

I'm very frustrated because I used knowledge I gained from a book on Java to set up and paint to a JFrame for my program, but it seems like no one else in the universe sets it up the same way and the only way to fix it would be a large amount of recoding. So help!

I get horrific image flicker with my program. I have no idea how to get rid of it. I know how to double buffer an applet, but this is not an applet so it does me no good. I have one "set" of images that never changes (P1_xxx) and then I have a "Background" (not sure that's the right terminology) image that changes when other variables change. Namely, when the player completes laps. They both flicker. A lot. Here's the code.

Everything I've read almost answers my question but is intended for the JFrame being set up a different way, within a JPanel or something else like that.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Game extends JFrame {
//all images
    URL url1=null, url2=null, url3=null, url4=null, urlhome1=null;
    Image img1,img2,img3,img4,home1;
    //screen width
    final int WIDTH = 1080, HEIGHT = 726;
    //car
    Rectangle p1 = new Rectangle(390,620,WIDTH/35,WIDTH/35);
    //constructor
    public Game() {
        //create the JFrame
        super("Racer Doom Squared");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        //load the urls
        try {
            url1 = this.getClass().getResource("Images/P1_Up.png");
            url2 = this.getClass().getResource("Images/P1_Right.png");
            url3 = this.getClass().getResource("Images/P1_Down.png");
            url4 = this.getClass().getResource("Images/P1_Left.png");
            urlhome1 = this.getClass().getResource("Images/Home1.png");
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        //attach URLs to Images
        img1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url1);
        img2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url2);
        img3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url3);
        img4 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url4);
        home1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(urlhome1);
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        if(p1Laps==0) {
        //home1
        g.drawImage(home1,0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,this);
        }
        int scale = (WIDTH/HEIGHT)*3;
        //Up
        int p1width1 = img1.getWidth(this);
        int p1height1 = img1.getHeight(this);
        int w1 = scale*p1width1;
        int h1 = scale*p1height1;
        //Right
        int p1width2 = img2.getWidth(this);
        int p1height2 = img2.getHeight(this);
        int w2 = scale*p1width2;
        int h2 = scale*p1height2;
        //Down
        int p1width3 = img3.getWidth(this);
        int p1height3 = img3.getHeight(this);
        int w3 = scale*p1width3;
        int h3 = scale*p1height3;
        //Left
        int p1width4 = img4.getWidth(this);
        int p1height4 = img4.getHeight(this);
        int w4 = scale*p1width4;
        int h4 = scale*p1height4;
        if(p1Direction==UP) {
            g.drawImage(img1,p1.x,p1.y,(int)w1,(int)h1,this);
        }
        if(p1Direction==RIGHT) {
            g.drawImage(img2,p1.x,p1.y,(int)w2,(int)h2,this);
        }
        if(p1Direction==DOWN) {
            g.drawImage(img3,p1.x,p1.y,(int)w3,(int)h3,this);
        }
        if(p1Direction==LEFT) {
            g.drawImage(img4,p1.x,p1.y,(int)w4,(int)h4,this);
        }
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  For an SSCCE that uses images, either generate them in code or hot-link to some (small) images available on the net.

Comment: Some variable are not declared, and they are `p1Laps`, `p1Direction`, `UP`,  `RIGHT`, `DOWN` and `LEFT`

Comment: *"Everything I've read almost answers my question"*  What question?  I don't see any '?' amongst those words.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  As well as that, missing 2 `}` and the import for `URL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are reading is telling to draw in the paintComponent method of a JPanel, not in a JFrame. Otherwise you lose the benefits of double buffering and other Swing goodies, so I'd believe it and follow it. Then add the JPanel to your JFrame.

If this still confuses, please ask, but also supply more information.

Comment: I was afraid of this. Thank you.

Comment: @speakr: not much to be afraid of. You should be focusing more on creating JPanels rather than JFrames anyway. They are much more flexible as you can put them into JFrames with ease, or JApplets, JDialogs, JTabbedPanes, other JPanels,... The same can't be said about a JFrame.

Comment: Well that is very good to know! I will look for a tutorial on converting a JFrame over to a JPanel. Thank you very much for your help these last few days.